# Why is my v-for statement not reacting to Vue properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have the following code

```
<marker-popup v-for="point in pointsArray" :position="point.latlng" :title="point.name" > </marker-popup>
```

with marker-popup defined here:

```
<template>
  
    <l-marker :position="position" :title="title" :draggable="false">
      <l-popup :content="text"></l-popup>
    </l-marker>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        name: 'MarkerPopup',
        props: ['position','title'],

        computed: {
            text: function(){
                return "<b>" + this.title + "</b><br>" 
                    + this.position[0] + ", " + this.position[1];
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

pointsArray is updated here:

```
addPoint: function(data) {

                let alreadyExists = false;
                if(this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]!=undefined){
                    alreadyExists = true;
                }
                this.pointsDictionary[data.uid] = {};
                
            
                this.$set(this.pointsDictionary,data.uid,{
                    'name': data.name,
                    'latlng': data.latlng,
                    'uid': data.uid
                });
            //    this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]['name'] = data.name;
              //  this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]['latlng'] = data.latlng;

                //  this.points[data.uid]["marker"] = null;
                if(alreadyExists){
                    console.log("exists");
                    var index = this.pointsArray.find(function(point){
                        return point.uid == data.uid;
                    });
                    //this.$set(this.pointsArray,index,this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]);
                    this.pointsArray.splice(index,1,this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]);
                }
                else {
                      this.pointsArray.push(this.pointsDictionary[data.uid]);
                }
              

                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pointsDictionary));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pointsArray2()));



            }
```

However, it does nothing to affect the v-for statement. Whenever the addPoint() method runs, it alters pointsArray in one of two ways

1. It pushes to the array - this works fine, v-for is perfect
2. It changes an element in the array according to what the Vue.js docs recommend [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). This does not work at all. My console.log statements tell me that the change occurs in pointsArray - Vue does not react to that change despite me trying their recommended approach for changing arrays.

I could, I suppose, remove the element and then just push it but that approach seems clumsy and this should work according to their docs.

Comment: Array.find finds the element in array itself, not the index.

Comment: Also why are you maintaining two versions of the state?

Comment: Ah good point on the Array.find @BertEvans. That didn't affect my code though - the console.log statements still showed that it was actually altering the array

Comment: v-for cannot iterate through a dictionary - I needed a way to create an array. I tried creating a computed property that would translate the dictionary into an array but it would always use the cached version of the computer property even when I used the this.$set function on the dictionary

Comment: Ok, well `v-for` can iterate an object, and a `computed` *should* work here. Let me look a bit.

Comment: `       let _pointsDictionary = this.pointsDictionary;
                var keys = Object.keys(_pointsDictionary);

                var values = keys.map(function(v) {
                    return _pointsDictionary[v];
                });
                
                return values;`

That was what my computed property was, for the record.

Comment: Can you try one quick thing though; add ` :key="point" ` to your `marker-popup`.

Comment: That actually just made it worse. The simple pushing to the array stopped working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146115/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-ben-cooper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was doing everything right but the [vue-leaflet package](https://github.com/brandonxiang/vueleaflet) doesn't play nicely with Vue 2.0 and refuses to properly react. Switching over to [this](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet) one solved all the problems.